# CGPoints inverting y values

Tags: ipad, ios7, sprite-kit

I'm seeing some weird stuff and not sure why this is happening. I'm adding a sprite with a position of x:490 y:680.

This gets positioned with an inverted y axis for some reason. Naturally, when I register for touch events and I get the location of the tap, it's giving a completely different CGPoint that looks like x:481 y:89.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Edit: Based on the documentation, it says that sprites follow their parent's coordinate system. Not sure how to change or know how this is set.

Just noticed CGPoint(0,0) is on the lower left corner as opposed to top left with UIView. Why is this default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprite Kit has its [origin at the lower left corner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH3-SW1) because this is the default coordinate system for all OpenGL apps.

To convert from UITouch locations to the Sprite Kit coordinate system, use the [UITouch Sprite Kit additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/UITouch_SpriteKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013279).

Comment: Thanks, that is what I end up doing, getting touch location in node as opposed to in view.